# Trying to find code not in functions.php, db, or directory to modify a wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got this php file of a wordpress theme (listify) and am trying to figure out how to modify the footer in the code snippet below.  However, I don't know where to find the code for the function shown in the snippet below.  I've looked in the functions.php, searched the entire directory and the database, but cannot find 'listify_content_job_listing_footer'.  Is there another way I should be searching for it so I can modify this?  Or is this a combination of things I should be searching for?

```
    <footer class="job_listing-entry-footer">

        <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_footer' ); ?>

    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added by the theme author for users to add customizations. From my experience with listify, wp job manager plugins might use it for something (or it might not). You could always check the plugin, but even if the plugin uses it, you can override it. It's meant to be overridden. Theme authors do this so users don't directly edit the theme templates. This makes it easier to update the theme in the future without the users site breaking.

You would use this in the child themes functions.php as:

```
my_function(){
//code here which will get displayed to the page
}
add_action('listify_content_job_listing_footer', 'my_function');
```

It will then execute when the page loads and  do_action() is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Wish I could upvote, but I'm too new.

Comment: You might need to wait a day or two, but I think you can choose the checkmark for the correct answer.